# Beep Noise whenever a new line in terminal appears (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

When I'm using Pycharm and running code, is there any way to make a beeping noise (or any notification) whenever a new line appears on the terminal?

Comment: Do you know `print('\a')`?

Comment: No.. Im not familiar with these. but I will research with it, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Using simple escape character `'\a'` can make the program ring in the **console** terminal:

```
>>> from time import sleep
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(i, '\a')
...     sleep(2)
...
0
1
2
```

This will print numbers every 2 seconds in my console terminal, accompanied by a ringing tone. Unfortunately, Pycharm's running window doesn't seem to handle it correctly. It only works in the console terminal.